# Layover in Athens for 2 hours

Tags: schengen, transit-visas, athens, ath

I'm traveling to the UK from Saudi Arabia. I want to book Aegean Airlines but it has a 2:25-hoursl layover in Athens. So I’m wondering whether I require a transit visa. I’m holding a Philippines passport.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area)

Comment: Thank you..it does help but I’m not sure yet.

Comment: @mlc For that to answer their question, the OP needs to know if Athens has an international transit area.

Comment: @lambshaanxy would it be possible to maintain a list of Schengen area airports that have such facilities (with hours of availability, as some do close at night)?  Would it be a good idea?  In any event, I've only flown through Athens on my way to or from another Greek airport, but it certainly seemed to be configured (like most major hub airports in the Schengen area) with an international transit area.